# SQL query regarding date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to answer the following question:

*Show all engagements in October 2007 that start between noon and 5 P.M*

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT EngagementNumber, StartDate, StartTime
FROM Engagements
WHERE StartDate <= CAST('2007-10-31' As DATE)
AND EndDate >= CAST('2007-10-01' AS DATE)
AND StartTime Between CAST('12:00:00' AS TIME) AND CAST('17:00:00' AS TIME)
```

However, the following error is occurring:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator.

I am running this on a SQL Server Database 2008R2 version and wondered if anyone could tell me why this is happening please?

Thanks

Comment: Is StartDate/EndDate a DATE field or DATETIME?

Comment: The error suggests you're trying to compare `DATETIME` to `TIME`, I would have a look at the data types in your `Engagements` table and then re-consider your query.

Comment: EngagementNumber StartDate EndDate StartTime StopTime ContractPrice CustomerID AgentID EntertainerID
2 2007-09-01 00:00:00.000 2007-09-05 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 13:00:00.000 1899-12-30 15:00:00.000 200.00 10006 4 1004
3 2007-09-10 00:00:00.000 2007-09-15 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 13:00:00.000 1899-12-30 15:00:00.000 590.00 10001 3 1005
4 2007-09-11 00:00:00.000 2007-09-17 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 20:00:00.000 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000 470.00 10007 3 1004
5 2007-09-11 00:00:00.000 2007-09-14 00:00:00.000 1899-12-30 16:00:00.000 1899-12-30 19:00:00.000 1130.00 10006 5 1003

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
       EngagementNumber, 
       StartDate, 
       StartTime
FROM 
       Engagements
WHERE
      StartDate <= '2007-10-31' 
      AND EndDate >= '2007-10-01' 
      AND convert(char(8), StartTime , 108) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '17:00:00'
```

`108` constant outputs as hh:mm:ss

Comment: What does the following syntax in the command actually do?          AND convert(char(8), StartTime , 108)

Comment: @bibah convert StartTime field as hh:mm:ss in 8 character length.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
SELECT  EngagementNumber, StartDate, StartTime 
FROM    Engagements
WHERE   StartDate <= '2007-10-31T12:00:00.000' 
  AND   EndDate >=  '2007-10-01T17:00:00.000'
```

this will work if startdate and enddate are of datetime datatype

Comment: From the question I would read that there are actually different columns for the date and the time information, so the `WHERE` clause should somehow reflect this. Besides that you're selecting engagements that start after October 31st and end before October 1st. I think you mixed something up with the compare operators.

Comment: @papatoob Thanks for pointing the mistake.well Op has posted the DB datas in comment.It shows date plus time(2007-09-01 00:00:00.000)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `datepart(hour)`:

```
SELECT EngagementNumber, StartDate, StartTime
FROM Engagements
WHERE StartDate <= CAST('2007-10-31' As DATE) AND
      EndDate >= CAST('2007-10-01' AS DATE) and
      datepart(hour, StartTime) >= 12 and datepart(hour, EndTime) < 17;
```